# Как добавить пробел в начале и в конце каждой ячейки всего фрейма данных?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

У меня есть такой фрейм данных:

```
 AAA|BBB|CCC|
 ___|___|___|
 0.5|1.6|2.7|
 ___|___|___|
 0.7|2.6|3.7|
```

Хотел бы получить такой:

```
  AAA | BBB | CCC |
  ____|_____|_____|
  0.5 | 1.6 | 2.7 |
  ____|_____|_____|
  0.7 | 2.6 | 3.7 |
```

Как это можно сделать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

попробуйте так:

```
df = df.astype(str).apply(lambda col: ' ' + col + ' ')
```

Comment: спасибо! Через 12 минут приму ваш ответ